# Runing two webapps from one server?

Tags: django

I have a server that contains the first webapp I evermade, the server capacity is half used (cpu nor hdd) but it still earns some money. I don't want to remove the app but I would like to host a new project there, however the setup is very ... let's say "my-first-app-style" bad. For exemple there is no virtual enviroment there.

This is the folder structure I am thinking about:

```
/public_html/
     /apps
     /core_app
     /3rd_apps #old-app django is here
     /static
     /media
     /new_app #this would be my new app
         /new app folders #with different django
```

The new_app would have it's own django and everything else. Currently my enviroment variables point to apps, 3rd_apps and core_app. I am not sure what would happen if I introduce a new app and point more enviroment variables towards the new_app folders.

Also, currently I am using nginx, gunicorn, postgres server and supervisor there.

I think using the same database server (and create a new database) for the new app should not be a problem. Supervisor should also be no problem. I think I can setup nginx to handle two domains in different locations.

My biggest fear is that the two djangos are going to fight each other without the virtual env. I don't know how to test this, because I have no free server.

Has anybody experience with this? Some advice how to do this?

Comment: Why don't you create two virtual envs? Each server runs on its own port, and you use nginx to route to the right server?

Comment: Furthermore I don't really understand why you need a server. Your local machine can be used as a test server. Even a raspberry pi nowadays can be used as a small server.

Comment: I hope that the directory name `public_html` is just left-over from the initial server configuration and your nginx is not actually serving this directory to the public

Comment: @DanielHepper: nginx is serving a location in core_app. public_html is what I got on the VPN to go with.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: That's true, my localhost can serve as a server for the django compatibility issue. I didn't think about it because I can not really test the whole setup localy (gunicorn, nginx and django app runing on a debian). But good that you mention it.

Comment: As everyone said you should make it separeted... but if you want keep doing that, add the proper configuration to call your both apps at your wsgi file

Comment: @Stefan: well you can run a Debian machine locally as well, or in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

You'll spare yourself a lot of future headache by just doing things the proper way now.

If you don't want to go all containers with e.g. Docker, I'd suggest

- one UNIX user per application
- virtualenv in the app user's home directory (`~/venv` for example)
- Git working copy in the user's home directory (`~/app` for example)
- static/media directories in the user's home directory (`~/var/static` and `~/var/media` for example)

Sharing the database server is fine as long as the apps have separate databases.

Comment: Seems like a bit of overkill to have both separate users per app *and* virtualenvs.